# Writing simple wxWidgets application with an OpenGL context in a frame

Tags: c++, opengl, wxwidgets, codeblocks, windows-7-x64

I would like to know how to use OpenGL with wxWidgets applications. For that purpose I have tried to use the code from the "OpenGL Cube" example from the wxWidgets library samples ( wxWidgets/trunk/samples/opengl - cube ). I am using CodeBlocks 13.12 on a Windows 7 x64 machine.

After creating a new wxWidgets 3.0 application project in CodeBlocks, copying the code from tutorial and adding "GL" folder with headers, I get many build errors ( undefined references mostly ). Before that, I have been writing simple wxWidgets applications and using OpenGL ( separately ) without major issues.

For starters, I would like to see a simple application that would create GL context inside a wxWidgets frame and, say, just draw a square, for simplicity. I think that would take much less effort than solving the build problems I have encountered, so I would be really glad if someone will be nice enough to provide a simple example code.

**EDIT :**

Here are the build messages, after unsuccessful build in CodeBlocks :

```
||=== Build: Debug in cubePrimercek (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
cube.cpp|37|warning: "wxUSE_GLCANVAS" redefined [enabled by default]|
O:\SourceCode\Libraries\wxWidgets3.0\include\wx\setup.h|1318|note: this is the location of the previous definition|    obj\Debug\cube.o||In function `ZN13TestGLContextC2EP10wxGLCanvas':|
cube.cpp|146|undefined reference to `wxGLContext::wxGLContext(wxGLCanvas*, wxGLContext const*)'|
cube.cpp|148|undefined reference to `wxGLContext::SetCurrent(wxGLCanvas const&) const'|
cube.cpp|146|undefined reference to `wxGLContext::~wxGLContext()'|obj\Debug\cube.o||In function `ZN12TestGLCanvasC2EP8wxWindowPi':|
cube.cpp|338|undefined reference to `wxGLCanvas::wxGLCanvas(wxWindow*, int, int const*, wxPoint const&, wxSize const&, long, wxString const&, wxPalette const&)'|
cube.cpp|338|undefined reference to `wxGLCanvas::~wxGLCanvas()'|obj\Debug\cube.o||In function `ZN7MyFrameC2Eb':|
cube.cpp|500|undefined reference to `wxGLCanvasBase::IsDisplaySupported(int const*)'|obj\Debug\cube.o:cube.cpp:(.rdata+0x248)||undefined reference to `wxGLCanvas::sm_eventTable'|obj\Debug\cube.o:cube.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV12TestGLCanvas[__ZTV12TestGLCanvas]+0x8)||undefined reference to `wxGLCanvas::GetClassInfo() const'|obj\Debug\cube.o:cube.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV12TestGLCanvas[__ZTV12TestGLCanvas]+0x368)||undefined reference to `wxGLCanvas::SwapBuffers()'|obj\Debug\cube.o:cube.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV12TestGLCanvas[__ZTV12TestGLCanvas]+0x370)||undefined reference to `wxGLCanvas::CreateDefaultPalette()'|obj\Debug\cube.o||In function `ZN12TestGLCanvasD1Ev':|
cube.h|66|undefined reference to `wxGLCanvas::~wxGLCanvas()'|
cube.h|66|undefined reference to `wxGLCanvas::~wxGLCanvas()'|obj\Debug\cube.o:cube.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV13TestGLContext[__ZTV13TestGLContext]+0x8)||undefined reference to `wxGLContext::GetClassInfo() const'|obj\Debug\cube.o:cube.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV13TestGLContext[__ZTV13TestGLContext]+0x1c)||undefined reference to `wxGLContext::SetCurrent(wxGLCanvas const&) const'|obj\Debug\cube.o||In function `ZN13TestGLContextD1Ev':|    
cube.h|18|undefined reference to `wxGLContext::~wxGLContext()'|
||=== Build failed: 15 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 9 second(s)) ===|
```

I have added a line which (re)defines wxUSE_GLCANVAS to 1.

Comment: there's a Open GL Cube example in wxWidgets.... :)  Seriously, your problems are likely to be build environment. Telling us the build errors is likely to be more helpful.

Comment: @gbjbaanb - as an edit to the question, I have added the build messages from CodeBlocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to explicitly link with `wxmsw30u[d]_gl.lib`, ensure that it is listed in your project linker options.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Are you sure I should use .lib, since I use CodeBlocks ? I have added "libwxmsw30u_gl.a" and "libwxmsw30ud_gl.a" to the project -> build options -> linker settings -> link libraries. As well as to the CodeBlocks -> MinGW -> lib folder. I still get 15 errors.

Comment: You shouldn't have the libraries to any folder, configure the project to use them from the right location instead. If you do this, you shouldn't have any errors about `wxGLContext` and `wxGLCanvas` symbols any more.

Comment: I have added "libwxmsw30u_gl.a" and "libwxmsw30ud_gl.a" from both "lib" and "lib64" to the linker settings -> link libraries in the CodeBlocks project. I have added the folders of these libraries to project -> search directories -> linker as well. And also to global CodeBlocks compiler settings in search directories -> linker. And still I get 15 errors. I am running out of ideas, since I am a beginner and the projects I did so far were simple.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a CB user so I don't know what's going on but clearly your changes are not being taken into account, if only because you should be getting errors when using 64 bit libraries in a 32 bit build. If you see the actual linker command line being used, it probably still doesn't include these libraries.

Comment: Ok I understand, sorry for asking you too specific CB questions. Maybe I will try with CB forums. But actually I can see the command line in the build log, and it shows these libraries linked. It is really confusing me.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about the CodeBlocks element in this question, but if your link command uses wx-config to retrieve the list of compiler arguments then all you need to do is add `--gl-libs`, as in:

```
g++ `wx-config --libs --gl-libs` -lGL -lGLU mycode.o -o myprogram
```

At least that's what works for me in UNIX, surely there should be an equivalent way to do this in Windows.

Comment: Relieved hours of frustration for me on my ubuntu machine.

Comment: This fixed my link gl problem on ubuntu, thank you.  I only had to change "`wx-config --libs`" to read "`wx-config --libs --gl-libs`" in Project -> Build Options ... -> top of tree -> Linker Settings -> Other linker options (Code Blocks v13.12)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the default binaries built for wxWidgets are not compiled iwth opengL support included.

You might have to rebuild wxWidgets with the `--with-opengl` flag.

Comment: The wxWidgets that I have are extracted from the wxPack. And honestly as a beginner I have no idea how they are compiled there and if they include the OpenGL support.

Comment: then I'd recommend a different system, Qt perhaps, or read up on the wxWidgets web site for instructions on building the library.

Comment: I can try find out more information about wxWidgets. I will not change the system because Widgets suit my purposes better than Qt and others, and also I have already been coding in it before.